# head movement prediction using different algorithms

Tags: matlab, predict

I am recently doing a project to design a simulation system for predictive head movement in virtual environment. However, I got totally confused how should I use simple algorithms like linear regression to predict the head movement assume that I created sinus signal as original head movement.

My idea was: take every 10 points from database, und do linear regression in oder to get the next predicted 10th point and store this in a new array.And my code are as following(which is not correct):

```
for i=1:(length(tout)-10)
    for j=1:(length(tout)-20)
        x=tout(i:i+10);
        y=theta_h(i:i+10);
        p=polyfit(x,y,1);
        yfit=polyval(p,x);
        %calculate predicted point after 10 samples;
        predict=@(x) p(1)*x+p(2);
        theta_c(:,j)=predict(x(i+20,:));
        i=i+1;
        j=j+1;
    end
end
```

[ORIGINAL CODE AS A PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3Rwx.png)

Comment: Do not post your code as comment. Paste it and format it properly.

Comment: How do I format it properly?

Comment: Please consider providing a [MCVE], i.e. define all variables needed to run your code. Please also specify the problem with your current code. Runtime errors? Wrong output? If so, which output do you get?